Response of the POST request to Flask server does not return the desired value
I am creating a backend server for small project (that any security problem is not an issue) and stumbled across a problem. I had to send JWT token to the frontend, but apparently the token does not arrive. This is the code for my Flask server:
@app.route('/api/user/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    data = request.get_json()
    username = data.get('username')
    pw_hash = data.get('pw_hash')
    
    cursor.execute('SELECT pw_hash, id FROM users WHERE username=\'{username}\';')
    data = cursor.fetchone()

    db.commit()
    if data and pw_hash == data[0]:
        return jsonify({'token': create_access_token(identity={'id': data[1]})}), 201
    return jsonify({'error':'Invalid credentials.'}), 401

And this is the code for the React frontend:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

const Login = () => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        const payload = {
            username: username,
            pw_hash: CryptoJS.SHA256(password).toString(),
        };

        try {
            const response = await fetch('/api/user/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(payload),
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                alert('로그인에 성공했습니다.');
                localStorage.setItem('token', response.json().token);
            } else {
                alert('로그인에 실패했습니다.');
            }
        } catch(error) {
            alert('서버 오류');
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
        // ...
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;

I expected to get at least something from the backend, but the console.log(reponse.json().token) returns undefined.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Edit:
This is the modified code for the frontend.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

const Login = () => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [data, setData] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        const payload = {
            username: username,
            pw_hash: CryptoJS.SHA256(password).toString(),
        };

        try {
            const response = await fetch('/api/user/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(payload),
            });
            const json = await response.json();
            setData(json);

            if (response.ok && data) {
                alert('로그인에 성공했습니다.');
                localStorage.setItem('token', data);
                alert(data.token);
            } else {
                alert('로그인에 실패했습니다.');
            }
        } catch(error) {
            alert('서버 오류');
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
        ...
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;


I'm pretty sure response.json() needs to be awaited.

See here. response.json() returns a Promise. Not the JSON data you expect. Therefore, if you query the property token, undefined is returned, because Promise does not have it.

@Detlef I added await to the response.json() but unfortunately it still is undefined. I'll add the modified code to the question.

I wrote a simple example based on your code. The code is modified in two places. I think the crucial difference is in the code of the database query. Your query didn't produce any results for me.
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    current_app, 
    g, 
    jsonify, 
    request
)
from flask_jwt_extended import (
    JWTManager, 
    create_access_token
)
import sqlite3

DATABASE = 'database.db'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your secret here'

jwt = JWTManager(app)

def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    return db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_connection(exception):
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()

with app.app_context():
    try:
        db = get_db()
        with current_app.open_resource('schema.sql', 'r') as f:
            db.executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()
    except: pass

@app.post('/api/user/login')
def login():
    username = request.json.get('username', None)
    password = request.json.get('pw_hash', None)

    cursor = get_db().cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT pw_hash, id FROM users WHERE username=?', (username,))
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.close()

    if data and password == data[0]:
        return jsonify({'token': create_access_token(identity={'id': data[1]})}), 201

    return jsonify({'error': 'Invalid credentials.'}), 401

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

const Login = () => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const payload = {
            username: username,
            pw_hash: CryptoJS.SHA256(password).toString(),
        };

        try {
            const response = await fetch('/api/user/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(payload),
            });

            const data = await response.json();
            if (response.ok && data) {
                alert('로그인에 성공했습니다.');
                localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
                console.log(data.token);
            } else {
                alert('로그인에 실패했습니다.');
            }
        } catch(error) {
            console.error('서버 오류');
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" name="username" onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
                <input type="password" name="password" onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                <button type="submit">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;

